# clang and __float128 bug/error

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

I've successfully compiled the current 3.3 branch of clang. But then C++ compilation of any file fails with the bug/error. Can that be fixed?

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/ostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:61:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/move.h:57:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/type_traits:256:39: error: use of
      undeclared identifier '__float128'
    struct __is_floating_point_helper<__float128>
                                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Did you take a look to this: http://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg31724.html?

Comment: Are you sure clang 3.3 supports __float128?

Comment: @Adriano Yes, I've seen that, but don't know if there was any progress.

Comment: @Martin:  Can't you find the header in question where _GLIBCXX_USE_FLOAT128 is defined and add the suggested edit yourself?

Comment: I just changed `-std=gnu++0x` to `-std=c++0x` and it worked for me.  Not idea why!  Clang 3.3 with gcc 4.8 toolchain.  Maybe things have changed in the last year or so.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can fix it with:

```
CXXFLAGS+="-D__STRICT_ANSI__"
```

Comment: This does not work for me (llvm/clang 3.7.1 with mingw 4.9.3 posix dwarf)

Comment: worked for me, adding set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__STRICT_ANSI__") after project definition to CmakeLists.txt. I'm using llvm/clang 4.0.1 with mingw 7.1 x86_64 posix seh

Answer (score 5):

I don't think `clang` supports `__float128`. It *may* be the same type as `long double` (which is 16 bytes in `clang`) so it may be a simple case of inserting:

```
#define __float128 long double
```

or:

```
typedef long double __float128;
```

somewhere early in your include chain.

I'm not guaranteeing that will work but it may, and it's probably best to try it out rather than wait until `clang` starts supporting more `gcc` extensions.

Either that, or switch to `gcc`, if that's an option. I'm pretty certain that `gcc` supports *all* of the `gcc` extensions :-)

Comment: Actually thats not a bad plan a quick -D"__float128=long double" may solve the issues ...

Comment: This is probably a bug in clang. Not surprising, since 3.3 is the current development branch and 3.2 hasn't even been released yet. The OP is pretty much using experimental code. Clang is supposed to work with GCC's C++ library.

Comment: NO! It does not work due to the template specification redeclaration, but I've found the solution ;-)

Comment: But I agree that this is a bug.

Comment: It's only a bug if clang states they support it. Otherwise it's just a difference in implementation - there's no mandated support for that type in ISO C.

Comment: experimentally, as of this writing clang 10 implements long double as IEEE extended 80-bit float. They make no claims and they don't support the gcc command line option to enable 128-bit long longs. It would be nice though.

Answer (score 4):

See http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13530#c3 for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to have this declaration. It works like a charm:

```
#ifdef __clang__
typedef struct { long double x, y; } __float128;
#endif
```

Solutions with `#define` don't work because of the template specification redeclaration error.

Of course this is a hack, and you must be safe. I want clang just for a few experiments, so it won't cause any troubles.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need the `struct`? What's wrong with just `typedef long double __float128;` ?

Comment: @paxdiablo There are two template specifications (already), something like: `template <__float128>` and `template <long double>`. With typedef you have the conflict.

Comment: I had the same problem because I compiled my code with Clang 3.2 and **-std=gnu++11**. After I changed to **-std=c++11** it fixed the problem.

Comment: I believe it should be `typedef struct { double x, y; } __float128;`, right? Only then will `sizeof(__float128)` evalute to 16 in both GCC and Clang.

Comment: With `Cygwin` and clang version 3.9.1, the above solution no longer worked because `__float128` is somehow already defined but disabled.  However, combining the above solution with `-D__float128=dummy_name_float128` did work.