# Travis CI with Clang 3.4 and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, travis-ci, clang++

Is it possible to get Travis CI working with Clang that is capable of C++11? (I want Clang, not GCC, I already have GCC 4.8 working in Travis CI.) It appears that the version that is there pre-installed is not C++11 capable. All my attempts at installing any newer version end up [failing because of this](https://travis-ci.org/wilx/log4cplus/jobs/19845125):

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:57:   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:269:39: error:
use of undeclared identifier '__float128'
struct __is_floating_point_helper<__float128>
```

I have seen the [`-D__STRICT_ANSI__` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792251/341065) but that clashes with other things for me.

Is it possible to get it working? See also my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/wilx/log4cplus/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Comment: awesome if you get it done =). by the way, other people are starting to use [BuildHive](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/), maybe it's friendlier [for C++](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/C+and+C%2B%2B+Builds)

Comment: Personally I'd like to know how, if you get this figured out. Answering your own answer maybe.

Comment: Related issues: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1379, https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/979

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a part of my .travis.yml files (mostly taken from [this file](https://github.com/beark/ftl/blob/master/.travis.yml)).

```
language: cpp

compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc

before_install:
  # g++4.8.1
  - if [ "$CXX" == "g++" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test; fi

  # clang 3.4
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:h-rayflood/llvm; fi

  - sudo apt-get update -qq

install:
  # g++4.8.1
  - if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq g++-4.8; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.8"; fi

  # clang 3.4
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -qq clang-3.4; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then export CXX="clang++-3.4"; fi

script: 
  - $CXX --version
```

**EDIT** because it can be very useful to add libc++ for travis. Up to my knowledge, there is no Linux package for libc++, so one has to compile it "by hand". Do not forget **-stdlib=libc++** in CXXFLAGS while compiling with clang.

```
install:
  # clang 3.4
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -qq clang-3.4; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++"; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then svn co --quiet http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx; fi

  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then cd libcxx/lib && bash buildit; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo cp ./libc++.so.1.0 /usr/lib/; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo mkdir /usr/include/c++/v1; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then cd .. && sudo cp -r include/* /usr/include/c++/v1/; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then cd /usr/lib && sudo ln -sf libc++.so.1.0 libc++.so; fi
  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo ln -sf libc++.so.1.0 libc++.so.1 && cd $cwd; fi

  - if [ "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then export CXX="clang++-3.4"; fi
```

Comment: Does this still work for you? No matter what I try, my build fails on Travis with `'iostream' file not found`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I didn't touch travis for 9 months, but I just run a test and yes, it still work today. https://travis-ci.org/richoux/Wall-in/jobs/61990830
Are you sure you give the following clang option `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I will compare your build with mine.

Answer (score 61):

## There is now [a better way to do this](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/pbdagcon/pull/7).

```
sudo: false
dist: trusty
language: cpp
os:
  - linux
compiler:
  - gcc
  - clang
install:
# /usr/bin/gcc is 4.6 always, but gcc-X.Y is available.
- if [[ $CXX = g++ ]]; then export CXX="g++-4.9" CC="gcc-4.9"; fi
# /usr/bin/clang has a conflict with gcc, so use clang-X.Y.
- if [[ $CXX = clang++ ]]; then export CXX="clang++-3.5" CC="clang-3.5"; fi
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5 # not sure why we needed this
  packages:
    - gcc-4.9
    - g++-4.9
    - clang-3.5
```

(The explicit `sudo: false` will let it build in Docker (for speed) even if you have a pre-docker repo, according to Travis support.)

Thanks to [**solarce**](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/266) at Travis support for noticing my error and fixing the docs.

- http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/apt/
- http://genbattle.bitbucket.org/blog/2016/01/17/c++-travis-ci/
- https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/.travis.yml (for up-to-date example)

Comment: What about clang++ with c++11 support?

Comment: See the [whitelist](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-precise) and [clang version compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: Thank you. I see the white list does not have clang++. So I am guessing c++11 with clang is not available for travisci? I am manually setting up libc++.

Comment: We are using C++11 and we build for both g++ and clang++.  See `-std=c++11` in [one of our Travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/pb-cdunn/pbdagcon/builds/68746420). The top-line of the Travis log indicates a dockerized build. You can examine [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/pb-cdunn/pbdagcon/blob/bc1814dcb2f2ef15176e89ae8437cb1dc0993553/.travis.yml) for that build also.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. I guess I will need to upgrade my `.travis.yml` files again.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help. I got it working. I am hoping that they continue their apt support.

Comment: Well, I only got clang-3.0 working with gcc-x.y in Travis via APT. I cannot select a clang version without errors. But I think the dockerized build is worth it. @JaredBurrows, if you got another clang version working, please post your latest Travis build.

Comment: Via manual installation I have gcc 5 and clang 3.6 working here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/OpenVirus/blob/master/.travis.yml.

Comment: Oh, you've lost the dockerized build. `sudo: required`. Yes, there are lots of ways with sudo. Look at the top of your Travis output. You will not see 'docker' in the name of the build machine.

Comment: My goal was just to compile it with gcc and clang with c++11 enabled. With your changes, I have have it on another branch: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/OpenVirus/blob/test/.travis.yml

Comment: Set the CC & CPP flags in the case of `before_install:` in cases such as `node_js` to avoid overwriting the standard `install:` commands. Saved the day for testing https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads on Node 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the clang developers fixed this when you build in `-std=gnu++11` mode.

Are you able to build with that flag instead of `__STRICT_ANSI__`?

- http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13530
- http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=184476

Comment: So instead of `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` we can use `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows: If you are using libc++, you wouldn't see this bug at all. This bug is due to a conflict between clang and libstdc++.

Comment: I am trying to get a project to build on TravisCI that uses C and C++. It compiles fine with gcc and clang(locally) but not on TravisCI, clang fails. I am using cmake. It looks like for TravisCI am missing the libraries according to Florian's answer.