# Travis CI with C++14 and Linux

Tags: c++, makefile, continuous-integration, c++14, travis-ci

Similar: [Travis CI with Clang 3.4 and C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111549/travis-ci-with-clang-3-4-and-c11)

How does one get Travis CI to work with C++14?

Here is our current `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: cpp
compiler:
 - gcc
 - clang
os:
 - linux
 - osx
script:
    make main
```

Here is our `makefile`

```
# Factor Pro

# Macros
CXXFLAGS = -Os -std=c++14

# Rules
all::main

main: main.cpp
    g++ -o main $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

It works on `osx`, but not `linux`.

Comment: You need to endure your C++ compiler supports C++14. Try printing "g++ -v". If necessary, add a package that's sufficient to compile your code.

Answer (score 16):

The default GCC and Clang versions are horribly outdated, and you'll need to install newer versions manually like this:

```
language: generic
os: osx
matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=gcc CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - g++-5
          sources: &sources
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=clang CXX=clang++-3.8 CC=clang-3.8
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-3.8
          sources: *sources
```

You can install multiple versions of Clang and GCC like [this](https://gist.github.com/nabijaczleweli/e53219d037c4ccb34f3c).

Note: I'm using `language: generic`, because if `language: cpp`, TravisCI's horribly-outdated `CC` and `CXX` override per-cell exports and it's faster.

I also recommend you use

```
    $(CXX) -o main $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp
```

Because the C++ compiler is almost never `g++` in the real world.

Comment: @PyRulez `*sources` is a "backreference" to the previous `&sources` at line 11 -- the whole tree from under the property marked by `&sources` is copied under the property marked by `*sources`.