# How to set/get Clang build on Travis for OS X?

Tags: macos, clang, travis-ci

How can I set/get Clang build with extra tools on Travis CI?

I need Clang-Tidy and some other stuff from Clang for OS X testing.

Comment: You can [install it through APT](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/)

Comment: Can you help me how can I do it?

Comment: Oh, with OSX you will probably need to use [Homebrew](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment#Homebrew), sorry. You can install those tools via `brew install llvm --with-clang --with-clang-extra-tools` in the `install` step.

Comment: I tried to install, but I got this message and error: "No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself." Can I use somehow a prebuilt binaries? And how can I install Clang with extra tools with APT for Linux? Thanks for your help!

Comment: On Linux you can install Clang with APT like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35113462/2851815). As for OSX, supplying `-v` to `brew` might help.

Comment: Building entire LLVM will take much longer than 10 minutes on Travis, so it's not recommended. Pre-build a binary and make Travis node download the clang-tidy binary from someplace.