# no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::__cxx11::string&)’ ifstream myfile(filename);

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

I am using Cmake and Ctest to try and test my code on Travis CI. If I use cmake to test locally I get no errors what so ever and I can make my tests. When running the test through Travis CI I get  loads of errors such as this one:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::__cxx11::string&)’

ifstream myfile(filename);
```

The filename is a string. Is travis running a different version compiler to my local setup?

Comment: Make sure you are including `<fstream>`.

Comment: Probably a version thing. Old versions of the standard library only accepted `const char*` there.

Comment: would you know how to use a newer version on Travis CI?

Comment: Im going to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110123/travis-ci-with-c14-and-linux.

Comment: Your code is C++ >= 11, obviously you ought to tell Travis that you need a particular compiler (and/or flags).

Answer (score 0):

The Travis CI C++ version needed to be updated.

here is the full .travis.yml

```
language: cpp
compiler: gcc

os: linux

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test 
    packages:
      - g++-7
compiler:
  - clang
script:
- export CC=gcc-7
- export CXX=g++-7
- gcc -v && g++ -v && cmake --version
- cmake ./Computing\ project/Test\ Mains/
```